# powershell merge csv's

Tags: powershell, csv, merge

I have a simple batch script that copies multiple csv files into one csv and i can't seem to find a way to do the same thing in powershell at a comparable speed. In batch it goes like this:

```
Copy "*.csv" Merged.csv
```

It copies roughly 20 3MB csv's to one file in mere seconds.

In powershell the closest i've come is:

```
dir *.csv | Import-Csv | Export-Csv allsites.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This method takes a really long time. Is there a method in powershell would be comparable in speed to the DOS command above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the same as you DOS command.

```
(get-content *.csv) | set-content Merged.csv
```

But either one are going to end up with extra header rows in the result file.

Comment: Is there a way to do this that only copies the top 100 rows of the CSV's?